# Using nested while loops to create a sum or powers list, python

Tags: python, while-loop, nested

I recently posted about this before but I am still not getting it to work properly. Here is a better description of what I need:
If your bases list is [1, 2, 3] and your exponents list is [2, 4], then the list your will return has two elements, one for each exponent, and is this: [1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2, 1^4 + 2^4 + 3^4].  Your mission is to calculate these elements using nested while loops and store the results in a list so you can return it at the end.

```
def sum_of_powers(base_list, expo_list):

    end = []
    j = 0
    i = 0
    while j < len(expo_list):
        sub_accum = []
        while i < len(base_list):
            sub_accum.append(base_list[i]**expo_list[j])
            i += 1
            end.append(sub_accum)
        j += 1

    return end

>>>base_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>>>expo_list = [1, 2]
>>>>print(sum_of_powers(base_list, expo_list))
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

The desired outcome is:
    [6, 14]
which is (obviously) 
[1^1 + 2^1 + 3^1, 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2]]

I dont think "j" is being added to properly and I cant figure out how to add up the elements in "sub_accum". I just cant figure this one out! Any help is welcomed! Thanks guys!

Comment: Erm, `[6, 27]`? How?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Haha oh fail on my part. [6, 14]. Good thing I said "obviously" right!? haha

Comment: Shouldn't it return `[3, 14]`? Basically if you enter the arguments `[1,2], [1,2,3]`, then you should get `[1 + 1+ 1, 2 + 4 + 8]` ?

Comment: no the first set of numbers is 6 because its 1^1 + 2^1 + 3^1 = 1+2+3=6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

append does not calculate the data when you put it in a list
thus you need to add the data instead of appending it
and you didn't re-initialize the value of i so it only runs through once

```
def sum_of_powers(base_list, expo_list):

        end = []
        sum = 0 #added sum
        j = 0
        i = 0
        k = 0 #added for loop in getting sum

        while j < len(expo_list):
            sum = 0 #re-initialize value to 0 for the next loop
            i = 0 #re-initialize value to 0 for the next loop
            k = 0 #re-initialize value to 0 for the next loop
            sub_accum = []

            while i < len(base_list):
                sub_accum.append(base_list[i]**expo_list[j])
                i += 1

            while k < len(sub_accum): #loop though temporary list to add its values
                sum = sum + sub_accum[k]
                k += 1

            end.append(sum) #end should be at level of 1st layer when all have been calculated and should only insert the sum of 'sub_accum'

            j += 1 

        return end
```

please use for loops next time so you wont forget to re-initialize your inner values

Comment: Check out mine as well - a little more similar to your original code.

Comment: @felicia glad I was of help.. please analyze properly to avoid confusion in the future and don't forget to re-initialize the values within the loops

Answer (score 1):

Why don't try this one:

```
def sum_of_powers(base_list, expo_list):
    exp_sum = lambda lst, n: reduce(lambda x,y: x + y**n, lst)
    return [exp_sum(base_list, e) for e in expo_list]

base_list = [1, 2, 3]
expo_list = [1, 2]
print(sum_of_powers(base_list, expo_list))
```

It's more functional and simple, using:

1. list comprehension
2. `map` and `reduce`

Comment: It was mandatory to use nested while loops for some god awful reason! But thank you!

Comment: @felica_rae, since @francis solved your problem. I will give you some style suggestions: avoid `while j < len(expo_list); j++` in a loop, instead use `for j in range(len(expo_list))` or `for index, value in enumerate(expo_list)`. It automatically increases `j` for you, making it less prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This does what you need with small modifications to your current code:

```
def sum_of_powers(base_list, expo_list):

    end = []
    endsum = []
    j = 0
    while j < len(expo_list):
        sub_accum = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(base_list):
            sub_accum.append(base_list[i]**expo_list[j])
            i += 1
        end.append(sub_accum)
        j += 1

    for i in range(len(end)):
        endsum.append(sum(end[i]))

    return endsum

base_list = [1, 2, 3]
expo_list = [1, 2]
print(sum_of_powers(base_list, expo_list))
[6, 14]
```

The main things were the placement of your `i = 0` re-initialization, and your `end.append`.

Comment: does this work if the expo_list has more than 2 elements in it?

Comment: @Kyle you shouldnt do [sum(end[0]), sum(end[1])]   as it only limits to two exponents.. what if the expo list contains more values then two?.. at least make a loop to return endsum dynamically

Comment: @felicia_rae My apologies, it does now.

Comment: @Kyle shouldn't it be simply just endsum.append(sum(end[i])).. the for loop should also be at level with the other while loop.. and what is the use of   endsum = [0] * len(end) ?

Comment: @FrancisFuerte Sure, there are alternate ways to do things; just altered it so it works under the conditions required.

Comment: @Kyle oh i see so you created multiple instances of endsum using the len of end which is this code "endsum = [0] * len(end)"

Comment: Yeah, but now that I look at it `for i in range(len(end)):
        endsum.append(sum(end[i]))` would have worked just fine too.